# Swift 3, function in protocol that return object of class that conforms to a protocol

Tags: swift

I've read so many articles about classes and protocols but still didn't found a solution. May be I just didn't understand all of them.

So there's a simple protocol (removed some parts not relevant to the problem):

```
protocol InfoObject : NSObjectProtocol
{
    var statusImage: UIImage? {get}

    func viewControllerForItemIndex(_ index: Int?) -> UIViewController?
}
```

But I would like the function `viewControllerForItemIndex` not only return an object of type `UIViewController?` but it should conform to the protocol `InfoObjectDisplaying` (not shown here) as well.

In Objective-C I would write:

```
- (UIViewController<InfoObjectDisplaying>*)viewControllerForItemIndex:(NSInteger) index;
```

Is this possible in swift?

Comment: Not currently – but [it will be possible in a future version of the language](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0156-subclass-existentials.md).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, you don't need to inherit from `NSObjectProtocol` in Swift :)

And no, you can't do this directly in Swift. You can require that an object conforms to a protocol or a class, but not both. However, you *can* declare `viewControllerForItemIndex` as a generic function and require that its type parameter conforms to specific requirements:

```
func viewControllerForItemIndex<T: UIViewController where T: InfoObjectDisplaying>(_ index: Int?) -> T?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've read about using generics already, but I was hoping there's a 'real' solution. :-)

Comment: For now unfortunately there isn't, as far as I know. :/

Comment: Not sure if syntax updated in Swift 3.1 but I just had Xcode correct this to `func viewControllerForItemIndex<T: UIViewController>(_ index: Int?) -> T? where T: InfoObjectDisplaying`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem like this:

```
protocol ScanningMessageViewProtocol: class {
    func showMessage(_ message: String, animated: Bool)
    func showMessage(_ message: String, autoHideAfterDelay time: TimeInterval?, animated: Bool)
    func hideMessage(animated: Bool)
}
extension ScanningMessageViewProtocol where Self: UIView {}

protocol CLScanBarcodeViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func messageViewForScanController(_ controller: CLScanBarcodeViewController) -> ScanningMessageViewProtocol
}
extension CLScanBarcodeViewControllerDelegate where Self: UIViewController {
    func messageViewForScanController(_ controller: CLScanBarcodeViewController?) -> ScanningMessageViewProtocol? { return  nil }
```

}

Use it like this:

```
if let messageView = self.delegate?.messageViewForScanController(self) {
        if messageView is UIView {
            self.view.addSubview(messageView as! UIView)
            (messageView as! UIView).translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let size: CGSize = self.view.bounds.size
            let cropSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: size.width * 0.7, height: size.width * 0.7)
            let cropRect = CGRect(x: (size.width - cropSize.width) / 2.0,
                                  y: (size.height - cropSize.height) / 2.0 - distanceToCenterY,
                                  width: cropSize.width,
                                  height: cropSize.height)
            self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 20))
            self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: -20))
            self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: cropRect.minY + cropRect.height + 30))
            self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 0, constant: 30))
            messageView.showMessage("this is message", animated: true)
        }
    }
```

Maybe that's not a very elegant way, hope someone could correct the mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays with **Swift 5**, I assume you can use the following code in your project:

```swift
protocol InfoObject: AnyObject {
    
    var statusImage: UIImage? { get }
    func viewControllerForItemIndex(_ index: Int?) -> (UIViewController & InfoObjectDisplaying)?
}
```

More likely usage:

```swift
typealias InfoAlias = UIViewController & InfoObjectDisplaying
protocol InfoObject: AnyObject {
    
    var statusImage: UIImage? { get }
    func viewControllerForItemIndex(_ index: Int?) -> InfoAlias?
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I think since swift 4? it is possible to use `func viewControllerForItem(at index: Int?) -> UIViewController & InfoObjectDisplaying`.

Comment: Hey Mika, I'm not sure, maybe you are right. Sorry, I overlooked that your question was for Swift 3. However, this works in Swift 5.

Comment: no problem. At the time I asked the question, Swift 3 was up to date ;-) But basically the question is not relevant now, since it is feasible with Swift 5.